# System normalizer of a direct product of groups

Tags: group-theory

**Definition**: Let $G$ be a finite group with prime divisors $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n$. A Sylow basis of $G$ is collection B = $\{1_G, P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_n \}$ of Sylow $p_i$-subgroups $P_i$ for each $i$ and such that $P_iP_j = P_jP_i$ for $1 \leq i,j \leq n$

**Lemma**: A Sylow basis of a finite solvable group generates a Hall system.

**Definition**: Let $G$ be a finite solvable group and $\Sigma \in \text{H}(G)$, the set of Hall systems of $G$. The normaliser of $\Sigma$ is defined as $$ N_G(\Sigma) = \{ g\in G \,|\, H=H^g \text{ for all} H \in \Sigma \}.$$ A system normaliser of $G$ is a subgroup of the form $N_G(\Sigma)$ for some $\Sigma \in \text{H}(G)$

Then equivalently, $N_G(\Sigma) =  N(\text{B}) = \bigcap \, \{ N_G(P) \,|\, P\in \text{B} \}$.

---

> **Problem**: Let $G =A \times B$ be a finite solvable group. If $D$ is a system normalizer of $G$, then there exists system normalizers $D_A$ and $D_B$ of $A$ and $B$ respectively such that $D = D_A \times D_B$.

I know that any Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, say $S$, can be expressed as $S = P \times Q$, where $P$ and $Q$ are Sylow $p$-subgroups of $A$ and 
$B$ respectively.

For instance, let $|A| = p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}$ and $|B| =p_1^{\beta_1}p_2^{\beta_2} p_3^{\beta_3}$. If B${_A} = \{ 1, P_1, P_2 \}$ is a Sylow basis for $A$ and B$_B = \{ 1, Q_1, Q_2, Q_3 \}$ is a Sylow basis of $B$, then B $= \{ 1 \times 1, P_1 \times Q_1, P_2 \times Q_2, 1 \times Q_3 \}$ is a Sylow basis for $G = A \times B$.

Then \begin{align} D = N_G(\text{B}) & = N_G(1 \times 1) \cap N_G(P_1 \times Q_1) \cap N_G(P_2 \times Q_2) \cap N_G(1 \times Q_3 ) \\\\ &= N_A(1) \times N_B(1) \cap N_A(P_1) \times N_B(Q_1) \cap N_A(P_2) \times N_B(Q_2) \cap N_A(1) \times N_B(Q_3) \\\\ &= (N_A(1) \cap N_A(P_1) \cap N_A(P_2) \cap N_A(1)) \times (N_B(1) \cap N_B(Q_1) \cap N_B(Q_2) \cap N_B(Q_3)) \\\\ &= N_A(\text{B}_A) \times N_B(\text{B}_B)  \\\\ &= D_A \times D_B \end{align}

I'm not sure if this is the correct way of appoaching the problem

Comment: This is the convention used in Finite Soluble Groups by Doerk and Hawkes. I think this is done to ensure that the Sylow bases of a group is preserved under epimorphisms. Also the Sylow basis generates Hall $\pi$-subgroups with $\pi = \emptyset$ corresponding to the identity subgroup

Comment: @DietrichBurde The trivial subgroup is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of any finite group $G$ for which $p$ does not divide $|G|$.

Comment: I have spent several minutes reading this, and I am unsure what you are asking and what you are trying to prove.

Comment: @DerekHolt, I want to show that a system normaliser $D$ of $G = A \times B$ is the direct product of a system normaliser of $A$ and $B$. I did not find this result in any journal papers or even in Phillip Hall's initial paper on system normalisers. I pressume this result is true?. I was approaching the problem by looking at the Sylow bases of $G$ and that of the factors $A$ and $B$ (as the system normaliser is related to the Sylow basis), but I'm not sure if this the correct way

Comment: Yes the result is true. But you seem to be trying to prove that the direct product of system normalizers of $A$ and $B$ is a system normalizer of $A \times B$ rather than what you stated, which is the converse. But both the statement and its converse are true, and they follow immediately from the fact that you stated that Sylow subgroups of $A \times B$ are themselves direct products, and hence so are their normalizers.